# Auto-refresh div containing Google map with Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, google-maps

I have a div containing a map from Google in a Laravel view, this view receives a JSON array containing coordinates from a MySQL database to insert markers on the map, and I want the div to refresh automatically after a certain amount of time in case a new record is entered on the database.

index function from the controller that sends the array when the view first loads:

```
public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::guest())
        {
            return redirect('home');
        }
        else{
            $user = Auth::user();
            $data = Reading::where('reg_id', $user->regNumber)->get();
            return view('readings.index', ['data'=>$data]);
        }
     }
```

After the page loads, another function is prepared to start refreshing the div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#map').load('refresh',function () {
          initMap(); //function that generates map with markers
        });
      },20000);
      });
```

This calls another function from the controller:

```
public static function refresh()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $data = Reading::where('reg_id', $user->regNumber)->get();
        return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

It goes ok when the page loads, but when the div refreshes for the first time I get a warning from the browser's inspector: "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." and I see the array get sent multiple times.

Obviously my idea is problematic, so I'm trying to find a way to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way it will be over ajax request.

Ajax request can return html so you will call ajax take response and put it inside "old" div.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that